# how do I speed test (benchmark) CUDA?

Tags: nvidia, cuda, testing

Just installed Nvidia CUDA (Ubuntu 15.04) and I would like to run a speed test to compare GPU use with cuda and without it.

Comment: You could use the 3d modelling program blender. It supports Cuda, but has to be manually enabled.  You'd want to grab a file from blendswap to render. You could also install the phoronix benchmark tool. That's probably the best option, it's a collection of various benchmark programs, and the front end to run the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Install CUDA toolkit:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-keyring_1.1-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-keyring_1.1-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get -y install cuda-toolkit-12-4
sudo apt-get install -y cuda-drivers
```

Install test kit:

```
git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples.git
cd cuda-samples/
make
```

Now in  **cuda-samples/bin/x86_64/linux/release** folder you have all tests you can perform.